# Class paths with Java

Tags: java, arguments, classpath, cp

I am trying to figure out how I may be able to setup my classpath file for java so that it could accept a jar and launch a class file not in the same directory as the one the user is currently in.

My code below shows `java -cp .:jsoup-1.7.3.jar Class1` will allow me to launch the Class1 file without any problems if I am in the same directory as the Class1 file which also contains the jsoup file. However I am trying to launch it as if I were in another directory so I would try something like

```
java -cp .:jsoup-1.7.3.jar /pathtofile/Class1
```

However this doesn't work because you need to set the classpath correctly. How would I do this so I could do something like

```
java -cp {correct absolute class paths and arguments to include jsoup jar} Class1
```

Thank you in advanced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"." means the current directory in Linux. so you'll need to substitute (or add) the path to where your .class file is.

Comment: Not the best answer but I changed it to /pathtofile/:jsoup-1.7.3.jar Class1 and this worked